# Не работает hosts.deny

Tags: linux, debian, hosts

На ПК стоит `Debian 10`, захожу в `/etc/`, добавляю в файл `hosts.deny` строки с вредоносными `ip` (строки беру [отсюда](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mitchellkrogza/Ultimate.Hosts.Blacklist/master/hosts.deny/hosts0.deny)). Сохраняю измененный файл, дальше пингую один из этих заблокированных `ip` - **все прекрасно пингуется...** Захожу через браузер на тот же ip - **все открывается...**
Вопрос следующий: почему так происходит? Почему изменения в файле hosts.deny **НИКАК** и ни на что не влияют?

Comment: Потому что это а) древность, и б) не про ping/http. Настройте лучше файрвол

Comment: почитайте `man hosts.deny` или поверьте на слово: то, что вы предполагаете получить, не имеет к этому файлу никакого отношения.